# Cannot fetch data from mongo with Java

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm trying to fetch some data from MongoDB with java but I get this error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: state should be: open
```

I have tried everything. This is the line that crashes:

```
Document doctor = doctors.find(new Document("doctor_name", DocName.getText())).first();
```

Connects successfully and the collection exists.

Comment: Please post the exception's _stack trace_ and the relevant code.  In general, the code you had posted looks fine. Also see [IllegalStateException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalStateException.html).

Comment: Posting all relevent code may help.

Answer (score 0):

**java.lang.IllegalStateException: state should be: open**
Usually means the MongoClient is closed. Make sure that is not the case.

Comment: I only open the client and fetch the data, Richard, i dont close the client nowhere.